# failed to get report for ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin: Unable to load the mojo 'aggregate'

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, allure

I'm trying to create report with Allure, but it work incorrect:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project converter-testing: failed to get report for ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin: Unable to load the mojo 'aggregate' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.5': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
[ERROR] while locating ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AlureAggregateMojo
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.5, parent: ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.5:aggregate)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.5:aggregate
```

Use allure.version - 2.5, aspectj.version - 1.7.4, with junit, org.seleniumhq.selenium.
My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
...    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/converter-testing-results</resultsDirectory>
                <reportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/converter-testing-report</reportDirectory>
                <properties>
                    <allure.issues.tracker.pattern>https://issues.corp.twilio.com/browse/%s</allure.issues.tracker.pattern>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I've tried to use older versions of dependencies/plugins. Didn't work.
What's going on? Please help

Answer (score 0):

1.5 is not stable version, please use 1.4.23 for stable version or 1.4.24 for latest. Any way try to use the Allure [commandline tool](http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Commandline) to generate report.